# Bad behaviour detecting when several divs reach the top of viewport (only when a css class is defined)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, offset

I have this javascript to detect when several text boxes reach the top of the screen. When that happens, they should remain fixed on the top and the rest of the bellow boxes should go up over the previous ones while scrolling.

It's working well when the css for the .fixed class is not defined, but when I define .fixed class the stickyBoxOffset for all stickyBoxes became equal to window.scrollY when the first text box reaches the top of the window (you can see that at the console.log screenshots bellow). I suppose it's because the position:sticky applied is messing everything up, but I can't find any other way that works. I've also tried getBoundingClientRect() and got the same result.

Anybody knows what's exactly happening and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

```js
// STICKY EFFECT FOR SERVICES
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      var stickyBoxes = $('.service-text-box')
      for (var i = 0; i < stickyBoxes.length; i++) {
        var stickyBoxOffset = stickyBoxes.eq(i).offset().top
        // var rect = stickyBox.getBoundingClientRect()
        // var offsetTop = stickyBox.offset()
        console.log("------")
        console.log(stickyBoxes.eq(i).attr('id'))
        console.log(stickyBoxOffset)
        console.log(window.scrollY)
        // console.log(offsetTop)
        console.log("------")
        if (stickyBoxOffset <= window.scrollY) {
          stickyBoxes.eq(i).addClass('fixed');
        } 
        else {
          stickyBoxes.eq(i).removeClass('fixed');
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
.services .service-left, .services .service-right { position: relative; }

.services .service-left  .service-text-box { padding: 130px 115px; z-index: 2; }

.services .service-text-box.fixed { position: fixed!important; top: 0; width: 50%; height: auto; }

.greenBox  { background-color: #01C4B8; color: white; height:200px }

.yellowBox { background-color: #FFC43D; color: white; height:200px }

.blueBox   { background-color: #084559; color: white; height:200px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 service-left p-0">
    <div class="greenBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-1">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            asdfasdf
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yellowBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-2">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="greenBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-3">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blueBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-4">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="greenBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-5">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blueBox service-text-box" id="service-text-box-6">
        <div class="service-title">asdfasdf</div>    
        <div class="service-detail">
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfasdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE (23/05/2023):

I've realised the strange behaviour is, in fact (and as I supposed), because when I make a div position:fixed it goes out of the space that the rest of the divs are using so the second div goes up and then the condition for the second div becomes also true and then for the third and so on for all of them.

So I tried two options:

1. Create an already fixed positioned duplicate for each div and show or hide it depending on if the condition of the equivalent div reaching the top of the window is true or not.
2. Translate the second div a distance equivalent to the first div height when the first div reaches the top of the window.

For both options everything is messed up specially when going up, once I position:fixed one element everything changes and seems to be undoable when scrolling up.

Any FrontEnd master who knows a better way to achieve this effect?

Thank you very much!

Option1:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var stickyBoxes = $('.service-text-box')
    for (var i = 0; i < stickyBoxes.length; i++) {
      var stickyBoxOffset = stickyBoxes.eq(i).offset().top
      var boxNum = stickyBoxes.eq(i).attr('id').charAt(stickyBoxes.eq(i).attr('id').length-1)
      if (stickyBoxOffset <= window.scrollY) {
        $('#service-text-box-fixed-' + boxNum).removeClass('d-none');
        $('#service-text-box-' + boxNum).addClass('d-none');

      } 
      else {
        $('#service-text-box-fixed-' + boxNum).addClass('d-none');
        $('#service-text-box-' + boxNum).removeClass('d-none');
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Option2:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var stickyBoxes = $('.service-text-box')
    for (var i = 0; i < stickyBoxes.length; i++) {
      var stickyBoxOffset = stickyBoxes.eq(i).offset().top
      // var boxNum = stickyBoxes.eq(i).attr('id').charAt(stickyBoxes.eq(i).attr('id').length-1)
      if (stickyBoxOffset <= window.scrollY) {
        // stickyBoxes.eq(i+1).css("transform","translateY("+stickyBoxes.eq(i+1).height()+"px)")
        stickyBoxes.eq(i+1).css("transform","translateY("+stickyBoxes.eq(i).height()+"px)")
        stickyBoxes.eq(i).css("transform","translateY(0)")
        stickyBoxes.eq(i).addClass("fixed")
      } 
      else {
        stickyBoxes.eq(i+1).css("transform","translateY(0)")
        stickyBoxes.eq(i).removeClass("fixed")
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Scrolling your snippet produces errors. Could. You cure those?

Comment: Sorry, I thought jQuery was accepted by default. It's working now.

Comment: Have you looked at position: sticky: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yes, I've tried with sticky as well and it didn't work I don't know why. I read that sticky needs a parent with defined height. I tried like that and didn't work. I suppose the best solution is something using sticky, but I need to modify the sticky default behavior because the boxes coming from bellow need to go over the one sticked. And those coming from bellow need to get stick as well. 
Any idea why sticky could not work even at normal behavior? Thanks!